# Is the statement "Unicode encoding" accurate?

Tags: unicode, encoding, terminology

Many tutorials mention the term "Unicode encoding", but I feel this is inappropriate.

From my understanding, Unicode is just a character set, not an encoding. The so-called encoding should be a storage method of Unicode characters, such as UTF-8 encoding, GBK encoding, GB2312 encoding, etc. They encode characters into byte sequences, and different encoding rules can result in different byte sequences. So I don't think the statement "Unicode encoding" is accurate.

Comment: There is no single "Unicode encoding", but maybe the tutorials you refer to use it informally to mean any encoding that can represent all sequences of Unicode scalar values (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, etc.)? (Though the author might also simply have no idea what they are talking about. Unfortunately happens often.) What would be an example for a use of this term in a tutorial?

Comment: @user17732522 For example, for python's encode and decode methods, encode is used to convert a string into a byte sequence, and decode is used to convert a byte sequence into a string. Some tutorials mentioned that for byte sequences, it may have many encoding forms, but for strings, there is only one encoding, and that is Unicode encoding. I feel like the Unicode encoding here is not quite accurate.

Comment: Yes, in that case the string type represents a sequence of Unicode code points. That's not usually called an "encoding" as far as I am aware. As the Python functions `decode` and `encode` hint at, the string is a decoded state and the byte string is an encoded state.

Comment: @user17732522 in Python 2 there was some confusion because the `str` type actually specified bytes instead of code points.  But Python 3 fixed that, and nobody should be caring about Python 2 anymore.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, I assumed Python 3 in the exchange above, otherwise what OP paraphrased from the tutorial wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: @user17732522 depending on the age of the tutorial it still might be relevant.

Comment: Your question would have been greatly improved if you had actually provided some examples of _"Unicode encoding"_ that bother you, because its use is not inherently wrong at all. For example, it appears 141 times (!!!) in the [Unicode 15.0 Core Specification](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/UnicodeStandard-15.0.pdf), particularly within the phrase _"Unicode encoding form(s)"_, and I strongly doubt that their use of that phrase is _"inappropriate"_. Without some specific context(s) your question is not really meaningful, and invites opinion based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Unicode is a set of systems, including a list of code points, and multiple encodings that transform a sequence of code points to a series of code units (e.g. bytes for UTF-8, 16-bit values for UTF-16, etc.).

However, historically, Unicode started as purely a 16-bit encoding. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#History), quoting from the original 1988 proposal:

> Unicode is intended to address the need for a workable, reliable world text encoding. Unicode could be roughly described as "wide-body ASCII" that has been stretched to 16 bits to encompass the characters of all the world's living languages. In a properly engineered design, 16 bits per character are more than sufficient for this purpose.

The original intent was to only encode characters in common, modern usage, which the spec assumed would be well served with 16 bits. However, this was a short-sighted assumption, and Unicode 2.0 expanded the code point range by introducing the "surrogate pair" system into the 16-bit encoding. This retroactively named the Unicode 1.0 (then just called "Unicode") encoding as "UCS-2", and the new 16-bit encoding with surrogates was named "UTF-16".

Due to these historical factors, several systems and documentation may still say "Unicode" when they really mean "UTF-16" or "UCS-2". Windows is a common example, I'm pretty sure I've seen a number of places that say "Unicode" but produce UTF-16 Little Endian.

Comment: "_Due to these historical factors, several systems and documentation may still say "Unicode" when they really mean "UTF-16" or "UCS-2"._": That is however not the situation that OP seems to have in mind according to the question comments. Instead they seem to have read something claiming that Python's (decoded) string type had an "Unicode encoding".

Comment: I think Microsoft is the prime offender.  They started using the term "Unicode" in their documentation when there was only one form, and never changed.

Comment: I'm curious in what encoding are unicode characters in Python stored by default? Will it be consistent with `sys.getdefaultencoding()` ?

Comment: @korangarleo no it won't.  Python actually uses multiple encodings internally and tracks which one any individual string is using.  This is completely transparent to your program.